# Can't create a new web site in IIS

Tags: iis

I want to add a new web site to my IIS 5.1 server.

I start the IIS MMC snap in, I select "Web Sites" from the tree and right click.  "New" is not on the menu.  Any idea why it's missing?

I am a local administrator of this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create website only on server edition.
If your are on a XP it's perfectly normal.

Comment: That would definately explain it.  Thanks1

Comment: And I just tried the same thing on a server with a much more positive result.

Comment: Nice and quick answer Manu!